# Using Jaxb to convert java object to xml <RECORDS> <RECORD num='1'> how get the num="1" when marshalling to xml

Tags: jaxb

I need to convert my java object to the following xml format. I know how to use jaxb for that. I'm stuck on how to set num='1', num='2' next to the RECORD field:

```
<AVS_TRANSACTIONS>
    <VERSION>1.0</VERSION>
    <DATE_CREATED>20120530</DATE_CREATED>
        <RECORDS>
            <RECORD num='1'>
                <BANK_BRANCH_CD></BANK_BRANCH_CD>
                <BANK_ACC></BANK_ACC>
                <BANK_ACC_TYPE></BANK_ACC_TYPE>
                <ID_NUMBER></ID_NUMBER>
                <INITIALS></INITIALS>
                <SURNAME></SURNAME>
            </RECORD>
            <RECORD num='2'>
                <BANK_BRANCH_CD></BANK_BRANCH_CD>
                <BANK_ACC></BANK_ACC>
                <BANK_ACC_TYPE></BANK_ACC_TYPE>
                <ID_NUMBER></ID_NUMBER>
                <INITIALS></INITIALS>
                <SURNAME></SURNAME>
            </RECORD>
        </RECORDS>
</AVS_TRANSACTIONS>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@XmlAttribute` like

```
public class Record {
    @XmlAttribute
    private int num;
    // ...
}
```